# np.savetxt formatting - how to eliminate ',' and '('?

Tags: python, numpy

thank you for the help in my last question.

I have an additional question, which is really basic actually:

using the code bellow:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('coord.xyz',dtype={'names':('id', 'type','x','y','z'),
                                     'formats': ('i4','i4','f4','f4','f4')})

f_h = file('sorted1.dat','a')   
m = sorted(data, key=lambda data_entry: int(data_entry[0]))    
np.savetxt(f_h, m, fmt='%s', delimiter='    ')    
f_h.close()
```

it was possible to sort correctly the data of
file 'coord.xyz' and save it in the file 'sorted1.dat'.
The data was like this

> (1, 1, -0.8835089802742004, 1.1118659973144531, 2.8823349475860596)
>
> (2, 2, -0.5829229950904846, 1.2082430124282837, 1.566588044166565)
>
> (3, 3, -0.4945560097694397, 0.02859400026500225, 0.7631300091743469)
>
> (4, 1, -0.7490050196647644, -1.2098779678344727, 1.3580570220947266)
>
> (5, 4, -0.30354899168014526, 0.24225300550460815, -0.8102440237998962)
>
> (6, 1, -1.0057859420776367, -1.2784860134124756, 2.719391107559204)
>
> (7, 5, -1.128898024559021, -0.08812399953603745, 3.508042097091675)
>
> (8, 1, -1.243878960609436, -0.2172279953956604, 5.247914791107178)
>
> (9, 1, -1.3797849416732788, 0.1959020048379898, -1.197553038597107)
>
> (10, 1, -0.25306999683380127, -0.2892940044403076, 5.424662113189697)

The problem is to eliminate the `','`s `'('`s and `')'` in the `'sorted1.dat'`.

Someone can give me a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't specify the format, or specify a correct one for each column. Start with:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('coord.xyz', dtype={'names':('id', 'type','x','y','z'),
                                     'formats': ('i4','i4','f4','f4','f4')})
m = data.copy()
m.sort()

with open('sorted1.dat', 'a') as f_h:
    np.savetxt(f_h, m, delimiter='    ')
```

To get the integers to display properly and the floats to use the simple decimal notation, use an `fmt` that's a sequence of formats:

```
np.savetxt(f_h, m, delimiter='    ', fmt=['%i']*2 + ['%f']*3)
```